# Once I set the Absolute Cognatic Succession Law, will that remain even if my heir isn't Cathar?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I've converted to catharism and set the succession law to absolute cognatic: will that remain set even if my heir is not a cathar himself?

Comment: Anecdotally, reading around, there seems to be inconsistent behavior in regards to no longer eligible succession laws. In regards to Absolute Cognatic, I have personally never experienced it being reset (in the past, I tended to do this via converting to Basque culture and back).

Comment: Having never tried Absolute Cognatic, I can't say for certain. However, I have on several occasions set Primogeniture succession and then promptly reduced crown authority to Medium (too low authority for Primo) it has never yet switched the succession law on me. So it would seem precedent is there for the answer to be no, it will remain the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Alright, so this question got me curious enough to dive into the game files to try to set up a situation like what you've experienced to see what the game will do.

So here we have King Guinea of the mighty and ancient house of O'Pig:

[image: king guinea o'pig]

Now King Guinea O'Pig has lived a long, long life, recently celebrating his 100th birthday. In that time, he's had two children, his eldest Gwenny O'Pig:

[image: gwenny]

And his youngest, Porky O'Pig:

[image: porky]

At the party, some say addled by advanced age, others by years of blasphemous, heretical lies, he made the declaration that his daughter Gwenny, a *woman* of all things, should have equal standing in terms of inheritance.

[image: laws1]

On his inevitable and swift trip to meet the reaper, Gwenny became the new ruler of Laigin, herself the mother of two children, an older daughter and a younger son.

[image: duchess gwenny]

Strangely enough, Gwenny rather *liked* the idea of holding onto power, and of allowing her daughter to inherit just the same as she did, despite having never held to her father's bizarre, unorthodox religious delusions.

[image: laws2]

As such, she made the decision to keep laws as they were, even if they contradicted the "norm" for her faith.

So there you have it. If this little experiment is anything to go by, it does indeed appear that even on the inheritance of a non-heretic character, a succession law allowed only by being of that heresy will stick. I may just have to see if switching Gwenny and Porky's ages has any effect.

Edit: After trying it out with the two children's age's flipped, I can confirm that even if Porky inherits rather than Gwenny, the succession law remains unchanged.

Comment: So bottom line is, your religion affects what changes to succession- and gender laws you can propose yourself, but not which laws are valid for your titles.

Comment: Yes. Once the law has been passed, changing religion will not nullify it, even if being of that religion was originally a requirement for passing it.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it but I think that even though you have the old succession laws in effect you can't name women to council and priest positions when your ruler is catholic again.